# Unable to execute callable statement, getting Parameter number 2 is not an OUT parameter SQL Exception

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench, callable-statement

I have created following procedure in MySQL workbench:

```
create procedure city(in CID int, out CName varchar(35), out CPopulation int)
begin
    select name, Population into CName, CPopulation from city where ID = CID;
end//
```

and following is my java code:

```
public class CallableStmts {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection con = null;
        CallableStatement st = null;
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world","root","password");
            String sql ="{call city(?,?,?)}";
            st = con.prepareCall(sql);
            int CID = 1;
            st.setInt(1, CID);
            st.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
            st.registerOutParameter(3, Types.INTEGER);
            st.execute();   
            String name = st.getString(2);
            int Pop = st.getInt(3);
            System.out.printf("%s %d", name, Pop);
            st.close();
            con.close();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);  
        }finally
        {
            try{
                 if(st!=null)
                    st.close();
              }catch(SQLException se2){ }

              try{
                 if(con!=null)
                    con.close();
              }catch(SQLException se){
                 se.printStackTrace();
              }
        }
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }
}
```

But on executing I get following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Parameter number 2 is not an OUT parameter

Even if I change callable statement to -> `String sql ="{? = call city(?,?,?)}";`

I get new error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Can't set IN parameter for return value of stored function call.

Comment: Add `create procedure city` output to your Post.

Comment: Sorry, I could not reproduce this one (Windows 8.1 x64, MySQL 5.5.22, Java 1.8.0_05, MySQL Connector JAR 5.1.18).  Your stored proc and Java code work fine for me. Please double-check you are connecting to the correct database and the stored procedure above has been created on this database.

Comment: I think that the order of your parameters is incorrect, maybe the first number of parameter is 0 and the final is 2.

Comment: I had same problem like you have _new error_ but I set index 1 of `OUT` and arrange other params accordingly ... This works for me!